# How can I convert a string which contains a variable name into a variable which can be referenced?

Tags: string, matlab, initialization, variable-names, function-signature

I am creating a function which scans files for a certain function and determines which variables (all are already initialized) are used as parameters for the function. Currently, I am able to derive a  cell array with strings for each individual variable.
The program takes this:

```
x = DummyFunction(a, b, c);
```

And returns this:

```
{'a'} {'b'} {'c'}
```

I am trying to convert these strings, which contain pre-established variables, into variables which can be called. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try use eval() function.

Comment: Do NOT use the `eval()` function. It's better to forget it even exists - since it only leads to bad programming practices.

Answer (score 3):

The function you're looking for is [`matlab.lang.makeValidName`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.lang.makevalidname.html) (introduced in R2014a):

> `N = matlab.lang.makeValidName(S)` constructs valid MATLAB® identifiers, `N`, from input strings, `S`. The `makeValidName` function does not guarantee the strings in `N` are unique.
>
> A valid MATLAB identifier is a character vector of alphanumerics (A–Z, a–z, 0–9) and underscores, such that the first character is a letter and the length of the character vector is less than or equal to namelengthmax.
>
> `makeValidName` deletes any whitespace characters before replacing any characters that are not alphanumerics or underscores. If a whitespace character is followed by a lowercase letter, `makeValidName` converts the letter to the corresponding uppercase character.

So for example:

```
>> matlab.lang.makeValidName(["_privateField", "some name"])
```

yields:

```
ans = 

  1×2 string array

    "x_privateField"    "someName"
```

I am not sure it applies to your use case, but you might want to look at: [Why Variables Should Not Be Named Dynamically (`eval`)](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/304528-tutorial-why-variables-should-not-be-named-dynamically-eval).

Perhaps what you *really want* to do is check whether variables with certain names exist, then do something accordingly - in which case you could use the [`exist`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exist.html) function:

```
tf = exist('varName','var')
```

So for example:

```
if exist('a','var') && exist('b','var')
  res = someFunction(a,b);
else
  res = someFunction(default_a,default_b);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try storing your variables in a structure and use dynamic field referencing. Here is an example:

```
variables.a = 1;
variables.b = 2;
variables.c = 3;

% scan your file here
% let's assume a and b are found in the file
variables_present = ['a', 'c'];

for i = 1:length(variables_present)
    % use dynamic field reference
    disp(variables.(variables_present(i)))
end
```

This will produce the output:

```
1
3
```

[Follow this link](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/) for more information on how to use dynamic field referencing: